# Making htmlwidgets in Rmarkdown mobile friendly

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

The default options of rmarkdown is to set the fig.width = 12.  I would like it to auto-adujust for the width of a mobile device if this is possible.

I'm hosting the following Rmarkdown at http://akdata.org/misc/leafletmobile

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document

---


```{r}      
  library(leaflet)
  leaflet() %>% addTiles()
``
````

It will adjust to the width of the screen when I play with different mobile devices in chrome devtools though. I have a physical Samsung Galaxy 5 that I'm testing with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think specifying a percentage `width` will give you the result you want.  Below is how you would do it in `rmarkdown` and here is a [live example](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/raw/50c3e2d2e3d8552d5a43/).  Unfortunately, if you specify a percentage `height` also, your screen will appear blank due to some bug somewhere, so it is not completely responsive, but it still adjusts nicely on my iPhone.

````
---
title: "responsive_leaflet"
author: "TimelyPortfolio"
date: "March 24, 2016"
output:
  html_document:
   mathjax: null
---

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# no help from a framework
#  just percentage height and width
library(leaflet)

l <- leaflet(width="100%") %>%
  addTiles()
l
```

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# demonstrate with Bootstrap
library(shiny)

fluidRow(
  column(width=10,l)
)
```
````

Comment: Thanks.  This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="htmlwidget-4092" style="width:75%; height:75%; position:absolute" class="leaflet html-widget"></div>
```

This block of code appears near the bottom of the source. The dimensions can be made to percentages, and it will auto-resize to fit the screen. Any percentages should work. Also, `position: absolute` is required to ensure that it stays in the correct location.

Note: I would recommend finding a way to shorten those massive links in the page source.